# подскажите, как создать связь с таблицами в asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, razor

по sql помню как вытаскивал данные из другой таблицы, а в asp.net mvc ну никак не могу и не найду подходящего материала в интернете

Comment: asp.net mvc не имеет ничего общего с вытаскиванием данных и с таблицами. уточните вопрос.